# Javascript variable not defined, using eventlistener in an external js file

Tags: javascript

Just started learning javascript and started to using an external js file.
Starting trying to make a password strength checker.
But pass keeps coming up as undefined.
I cant seem to find the problem.
Thanks for your time and help.

The js file

```
pass.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  stength();
})
function strength() {
  var val = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  var status = document.getElementById("length").value;
  var counter = 0;

  if (val != ""){
    if(val.length <= 6)
      counter=1;
    if(val.length >= 7 && val.length <= 10)
      counter=2;
    if(val.length < 10)
      counter=3;

    if (counter == 1) {
      status.innerHTML="Weak";
      status.style.background="#fc2407";
      status.style.color="#ffffff";
    }
    if (counter == 2) {
      status.innerHTML="Good";
      status.style.background="#fc9e07";
      status.style.color="#ffffff";
    }
    if (counter == 3) {
      status.innerHTML="Strong";
      status.style.background="#21dd53";
      status.style.color="#ffffff";
    }
  }
}
```

The html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap text-center">
      <p class="head">Enter Password</p>
      <input type="password" id="pass"/>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap text-center">
      <p class="head"> Password Strength</p>
      <p ckass="strength" id="length"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the error in console?

Comment: What's "pass"? Is it supposed to be a global representing the DOM element with that ID (noting that not all browsers act the same way in this regard)?

Comment: error on console is:ReferenceError: pass is not definedindex.js:6:1

Comment: pass is so when the user inputs a password it runs the strength function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do that!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap text-center">
      <p class="head">Enter Password</p>
      <input type="password" id="pass"/>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap text-center">
      <p class="head"> Password Strength</p>
      <p ckass="strength" id="length"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`<script ...` is just before `</body>`  => HTML is a top down interpreter too

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

If this is all your code, it seems like you never actually defined what pass is.
Try putting this at the top of your code before you reference `pass`.

`var pass = document.getElementById('pass');`

So your code should look something like this.

```
var pass = document.getElementById('pass');
pass.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  stength();
})
```

Or if you are not going to reference that variable again you can just do it this way.

```
document.getElementById('pass').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  stength();
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I have tried 
```
var pass = document.getElementById('pass');
```
However I get the following error:
TypeError: pass is nullindex.js:9:1

Comment: @Newt Oh yes, I missed the part that you referenced your script BEFORE you create the elements on the page. My apologies. I see that Mister just posted the fix for that. I would hate to just copy that in my answer.

Comment: Your help is still greatly appreciated :)